# Combining two regex for ASP.NET MVC data annoation

Tags: c#, asp.net, regex, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I have two regexes.

One is for no space at the beginning and end but there can be a space in between words:

```
^[^\s]+(\s+[^\s]+)*$
```

And the second one is for allowing some special characters:

```
 ([^\\~!@#$%^&*()+=?<>|/""]*)
```

Now, I want to combine both regex into a single regex.

I have tried with `|` sign suggested in another post but that is not working for me.

I am using ASP.NET MVC data annotations.

```
Valid are:
"A"
"A."
"A,"
"A'S"
Invalid are:
 " A "
 " A"
 " B"
 "A@"
 "A!"
```

Comment: Can you post valid inputs

Comment: It sounds like [Trim](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t97s7bs3%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) does exactly what your first is doing... Can you please explain what "not working" entails too?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use one regex to restrict the other within a lookahead:

```
^(?=([^\\~!@#$%^&*()+=?<>|/""]*)$)[^\s]+(\s+[^\s]+)*$
```

See [demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%5E(%3F%3D(%5B%5E%5C%5C%7E!%40%23%24%25%5E%26*()%2B%3D%3F%3C%3E%7C%2F%22%22%5D*)%5Cr%3F%24)%5B%5E%20%5D%2B(%20%2B%5B%5E%20%5Cn%5D%2B)*%5Cr%3F%24&i=valid%20are%20%0D%0AA%0D%0AA.%0D%0AA%2C%0D%0AA%27S%0D%0Ainvalid%20are%20%0D%0A%20A%20%0D%0A%20A%0D%0A%20B%0D%0AA%40%0D%0AA!&o=m) (note I added `\r?` for demo purpose in multiline mode, and had to replace `\s` with literal space, but I guess that will not be necessary).

Comment: Does it work for you? If not, or you have doubts, please provide the exact requirements, and if possible, the code where you are using the regex patterns.